# All Aboard..Hop onto the Power Train to reach Destination Unity

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, knowledge, no-computers

Your goal is to reach the destination unity.

starting from $3462$ with three intermediate stops.

You are allowed to use only 2 mathematical operations..multiplication and Exponentiation.

All the digits from the previous step have to be used only once in the same order they appear.

$A$.  $3462$

$B$.   $2916$

$C$.  $512$

$D$.  $10$

Please provide the journey details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

> First step:
>  $3^4*6^2$
>  Second step:
>  $2^9*1^6$
>  Third step:
>  $5^1*2$

Comment: Great,..Fourth..obvious..put it in

Comment: Thanks, but I thought the destination is 10.

Comment: Destination is unity..see whether you can reach the same destination starting with 2592.

Comment: @Uvc Destination infinity: `(2^5)*(9^2)=2592` :P

Comment: You cannot reach unity..you will be in loop

Comment: @Uvc I know I was joking, that's why I said infinity. It's just that the first combination I tried gave me exactly the same number. Real answer: 2*5*9*2=180, 1*8^0=1!